# Delete data from now till specified date in textbox in userform

Tags: vba, delete-row, userform

I have several sheets with data, all starting with "input" in the sheetname and all having a date column in column A. I want to create a userform that allows the user to insert a date in a textbox. This date will refer to the date column in the specified sheets. When the user has clicked "Okay", the macro should delete all rows in the sheets from Now() till the specified date. In other words it starts from the bottom and deletes upwards. The rows are not initially sorted according to date. This is what I have so far:

```
Sub Rens_date()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lcol
Dim iCntr As Long
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
With wb
    lRow = wb.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lcol = wb.Range("A" & Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Column
    Set deleterange = .Range(Rens_inputbox.Value, .Cells(lRow, lcol))
End With

For Each Row In deleterange
    If wb.Range("A").Cells = Me.Rens_inputbox.Value Then _
        deleterange.Delete
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Code is not working :/

Answer (score 0):

Place this code on your Okay button and this should work. It will iterate over the entire first column of all sheets which has a name that starts with "input_" looking for date between the current date and the date you typed in the `textbox`.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim actCell As Range
    Dim lastDate As Date
    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim currentCellDate As Date
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    lastDate = CDate(TextBox1.Value)
    startDate = Date

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If LCase(ws.Name) Like "input_*" Then
            For Each actCell In ws.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Columns(1).Cells
                currentCellDate = CDate(actCell.Value)
                If currentCellDate > startDate And currentCellDate < lastDate Then
                    actCell.EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```